# Store entered values in c#

Tags: c#

I have an gridview and for the same column but different row, I should store values.However, this code store just last column because it is entered last.How can I store all vlues while entering new data in different row?

```
private decimal _VValue
public decimal VValue
{
    get
    {
        return _VValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _VValue = value;              
        v.Text = _VValue.ToString();                
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to store it somewhere, in a `List` for example

Comment: make a list and add every new value in your setter

Comment: @FCin how can ı write?

Comment: @ Valentin how can ı make list?

Comment: @Valentin Textbox is different.It stores just one textbox value.I have two text box and I should store two text boxes value.but my code stores last one entered.

Comment: Please update the question with more details. Is the datagrid bound to a collection or a database? What does this collection look like?

Comment: @ja72 For below code For exp: I entered 1 in 1.texbox and entered 2 in .textbox it stores truely.But again changed the value of 2.text box=3.It stores 1,2,3 not 1,3

Comment: What textbox? **Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43654682/edit) the question** with all necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<decimal>`.

```
private List<decimal> values = new List<decimal>();

private decimal _VValue
public decimal VValue
{
    get
    {
        return _VValue;
    }
    set
    {
        values.Add(value);
        _VValue = value;              
        v.Text = _VValue.ToString();                
    }
}
```

This way, every new value is saved to a list.

If you want to access any value you can use do this: `var value = values[0]; // gives you first value in list`

Comment: Textbox is different.It stores just one textbox value.I have two text box and I should store two text boxes value.but my code stores last one  entered.

Comment: So you can use this code twice and change the names of the vataibles and methods

Comment: @itay_421 No, I mean it is gridview same column but different row

Comment: @FCin No, I mean it is gridview same column but different row

Comment: @harry please make your question more clear and specific, because I don't understand what you are trying to achive.

Comment: @ itay_421 I edddited question

Comment: @FCin For exp: I entered 1 in 1.texbox and entered 2 in .textbox it stores truely.But again changed the value of 2.text box=3.It stores 1,2,3 not 1,3

Comment: @harry show us how your gridview looks like, xaml and .cs code.